# Open web browser on local machine from ssh

Tags: macos, browser, ssh, windows-10, putty

I am using PuTTY to ssh from a Windows 10 machine into macOS.

I need to run a script that deploys some instances on AWS. As a security measure, the script opens a browser directed to an AWS login portal, and requires me to sign-in and verify my credentials.

The problem is that the web browser opens on the remote machine (the Mac), and there is no way for me to sign-in and verify my credentials.

Is there any way to have the web browser open on my local machine, or to visualize the web browser on my local machine in order to log-in?

It's not possible to change the script that opens the web browser, but any solution that permits me to verify my credentials without altering the script should be acceptable.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-i-work-with-gui-tools-over-a-remote-server

Comment: ssh with -X option gives you gui too check it out

Comment: @avck a MacOS browser isn't likely to support X. The MacOS GUI isn't X-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppleScript to tell Safari to fill the form.
for example add this to `fillform.scpt` file:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://www.google.co.uk/"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('btnI')[0].click();" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Then you can run from command line:

```
$ osascript fillform.scpt
```

**Note: this requires enabling "Develop -> Allow Javascript from Apple Events" option in Safari**

---

also see [Making AppleScript fill form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22615180/making-applescript-fill-form) or [Using Javascript | Applescript to click button in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468058/using-javascript-applescript-to-click-button-in-safari)